# Need Help in Asp.net Api and angular 16 project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular16

Here is my asp.net Api Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<RstCustomer> GetAllCustomer1()
{
IEnumerable<RstCustomer> _List;
_List = iunit.RstCustomerRepository.Get();
return _List.Cast<RstCustomer>().ToList();
}
```

My angular service function:

```
GetCustomerList(): Observable<customers[]>{
return this.http.get<customers[]>('http://localhost:58252/api/RstCustomer/GetAllCustomer1');
}
```

My Angular Component where i have subscribed this Function :

```
this.service.GetCustomerList().subscribe((res:customers[])=>{
var jsonvalue=JSON.stringify(res);
console.log(jsonvalue);
this.customerList=JSON.parse(jsonvalue);
});
```

My Html Dropdown List:

```
<select name="CustomerID" #CustomerID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.CustomerID"
class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="!isValid && service.formData.CustomerID==0">
<option value="0">-- Select Customer--</option>
<option *ngFor="let customer of customerList" [value]="customer.customerID">
{{customer.customerName}}
</option>
</select>
```

I am getting value from console and loading value in dropdownlist but dropdown list showing white.

[image: My Dropdownlist]

For your more information i have already used asyn pipe with observable but i am getting same result.

Comment: It looks like the options render but without text. Are you sure that `customerName` is the right property name? Note that JavaScript is case sensitive. Maybe it would help to  add the JSON to the question. Also why are you stringifying and parsing the JSON? Angular already does it for you.

Comment: Yes Property name is correct.  if i use without json convertion i get same result this.service.GetCustomerList().subscribe((res:customers[])=>{
console.log(res);
this.customerList=res
});

Comment: Yes i got it. Customer Name was Camel Case. Thanks.